# UpdatePanel method not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

Within an `UpdatePanel` I am attempting to both bind to a `ListView` and export its contents to Excel.  These functions work fine independently (my 'Run Report' button binds the `ListView`, the 'Export to Excel' button exports a .xlsx file using EPPlus).  In order for the .xlsx export to work I had to create a `<Triggers> Postback` for the 'Export to Excel' button.

I want the 'Export to Excel' button to both bind the `ListView` and export the .xlsx. I have added the method that binds the `ListView` into the export method, but it seems to be skipping it.  I think I am not understanding some portion of the PostBack.

Here is the `<Trigger>`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="export" />
</Triggers>
```

Here is the `ListView` bind:

```
public void runreport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reportlv.DataSource = null;
    reportlv.DataBind();
    bindreportlv();
    elreportdiv.Visible = true;
}
```

Here is the export method with the runreport method embedded:

```
protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    runreport(null, null);

    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Payee", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));

    foreach (ListViewDataItem li in reportlv.Items)
    {
        if (li.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Date"] = ((Label)li.FindControl("lbldate")).Text.ToString();
            dr["Payee"] = ((Label)li.FindControl("lblpayee")).Text.ToString();
            dr["Amount"] = ((Label)li.FindControl("lblamt")).Text.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=summary.xlsx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Here are the buttons:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="run" OnClick="runreport" CssClass="button" Text="Run Report" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="export" OnClick="export_Click" CssClass="button" Text="Export to Excel" />
```

**Update**

Here is the Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        runreport(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are doing a full post back, are you sure you still have the data to bind again to the listview?

Comment: Possibly?  I added a if(IsPostBack) { runreport(null, null) } into Page_Load, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Show also your `Page_Load` method.

Answer (score 0):

`<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="export" onclick ="CLick" />
</Triggers>`

Comment: onclick isn't a valid attribute for asp:PostBackTrigger

Comment: Ah got it.  EventName is an attribute for AsyncPostBackTrigger rather than for PostBackTrigger.

Comment: <Triggers> <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="export" onclick ="CLick" /> </Triggers>

Comment: Tested.  AsyncPostBack doesn't cause the Excel file Open/Save prompt.